# Which Paypal API do i need?

Tags: android, paypal

I try to setup a paypal intergration in my android app where my webserver does the job.. I'm not sure how it works, i only know its possible for IOS.

sorry for the crappy explanation..

Comment: Already found it.. Mobile Express Checkout Library (MECL) is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found it.. Mobile Express Checkout Library (MECL) is what i was looking for.